# How do I set the log level for ony one custom rails logger in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

The examples I've seen for setting log level seems straightforward in most instances however how do I set the log level for my custom logger:

`config.active_record.logger = Logger.new("log/custom_log_file.log")`

According to the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels) I should be able to make one of the following calls
to set a log level to debug, but I believe this is a global thing.

```
config.log_level = :warn # In any environment initializer, or
Rails.logger.level = 2 # at any time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the level right after adding the custom logger:

```
config.active_record.logger = Logger.new("log/custom_log_file.log")
config.active_record.logger.level = 2
```